# What does this refer to in this case, and why am i parsing a variable into my variable to traverse?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey I was wondering what this is refering to in my case I thought it was refering to my class edit but I am a bit confused here is my Html code that I am looping 3 times to get 3 blogs to edit

code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < blogEntries.length; i++) {

        if(blogEntries[i]!=null){

                var title=blogEntries[i][0];
                var content=blogEntries[i][1];
                var date=blogEntries[i][2];
                var blogID=i;

                var blogEdit = '<form><div class="blogContainer" blogID="'+blogID+'">'+
                    '<div class="blogTitle"><input type="text" value="'+title+'"class="titleInput"></div>'+
                    '<div class="blogContent"><input type="text" value="'+content+'"class="contentInput"></div>'+
                    '<div class="blogDate"><input type="text" value="'+date+'"class="dateInput"></div>'+
                    '<input type="button" value="edit" class="edit">'+
                    '<input type="button" value="delete" class="delete">'+
                '</div></form><br><br><br>';



                $("#mainContainer").append(blogEdit);
        }
    }
```

Here is my edit click function where I am not getting why I am using the container variable to parse it into my jquery selector hope someone can enlighten me. This is in the variable container where we are finding the blogContainer but i do not get why am i parsing this into the other variable with titleCont, contBlog and dateCont

code

```
$(".edit").click(function(){

    //find the closet blogContainer to .edit
    var container=$(this).closest(".blogContainer");

    //look for blogid close to .edit .blogcontainer
    var editId=container.attr("blogID");

    //define val for the three text inputs giving them container variable to find the classes
    var titleCont=$(".titleInput", container).val();
    var contBlog=$(".contentInput", container).val();
    var dateCont=$(".dateInput", container).val();

    // First read from local storage. Take empty array as default value
    var blogEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("BlogContent") || "[]");
    // Use editId directly as index. 
    blogEntries[editId] = [titleCont, contBlog, dateCont];
    // Write back to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("BlogContent", JSON.stringify(blogEntries));


    });
```

Comment: Where is `this` in your code? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: edited now but it is the edit click function where I have this container variable refering to this blogcontainer I do not understand why am i using this in the .val variables with the classes

Comment: It is still not clear to me. Are you talking about they keyword `this` which has special meaning in JS, or not?

Comment: `$(this)` is referring to the `input.edit` button that you clicked, `$(this).closest(".blogContainer")` is the `div.blogContainer` element that contains that button, `$(".titleInput", container)` is the `input.titleInput` which is contained inside that specific `div.blogContainer` element. Basically there are several elements on the page with a class `titleInput` and you want to select the element that is located inside the same container as the button that you've clicked on. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context